# Jenkins on EC2 using ELB and Route53 record set Reverse Proxy issue

Tags: ssl, jenkins, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

This seems to be a very simple question that I can not find a simple answer to. Setup Jenkins on an EC2 instance. Then configured an ELB for the EC2 instance. Looks like I have the right configurations for the security group so that seems correct. The ELB has a cert attached to it from AWS Cert manager. Now I have added a record set in Route53 pointing to the ELB.

Go into Jenkins, configure Jenkins URL to match Route53 record set that is configured with the ELB. And NADA. Nothing, zero, zip. Keep getting Proxy config error. So, am I missing something here or is there another place to configure the Secure URL I want to use with Jenkins connected to the ELB?

Comment: did you put the trailing slash at the end of your url, like so `http://example.com/`

Comment: Tried that. Still had issue. Tried with and without. Will try one more time. But  it should be using the https://example.com as I need it to be secure

Comment: Yes it was configured with the trailing forward slash and still not good. Also needs to be secure which is why I had it configured with the SSL cert through ELB